# Como montar um header BMP (Bitmap) em C

Tags: c, header, bitmap

Olá.

Estou querendo montar um BMP em linguagem C. 
Recebo apenas os dados da imagem, tamanho dos dados, width, height, bpp.

Consegui montar a seguinte estrutura header do BMP:

```
struct BMPHeader
{
    uint16 signature;           // 0-1   magic chars 'BM'
    uint32 fileSize;            // 2-5   uint32 filesize (not reliable)
    uint32 filler1;             // 6-9   uint32 0
    uint32 bitmapOffset;        // 10-13 uint32 bitmapOffset
    uint32 infoSize;            // 14-17 uint32 info size
    int32 width;                // 18-21 int32  width
    int32 height;               // 22-25 int32  height
    uint16 nPlanes;             // 26-27 uint16 nplanes
    uint16 bpp;                 // 28-29 uint16 bits per pixel
    uint32 compression;         // 30-33 uint32 compression flag
    uint32 imageSize;           // 34-37 uint32 image size in bytes
    int32 biXPelsPerMeter;      // 38-41 int32  biXPelsPerMeter
    int32 biYPelsPerMeter;      // 32-45 int32  biYPelsPerMeter
    uint32 colorsUsed;          // 46-49 uint32 colors used
    uint32 importantColorCount; // 50-53 uint32 important color count
};
```

Como mencionado acima, boa parte das informações de header, recebo de uma aplicação em java, exceto essas:

```
int32 biXPelsPerMeter;      // 38-41 int32  biXPelsPerMeter
int32 biYPelsPerMeter;      // 32-45 int32  biYPelsPerMeter
```

Alguém sabe dizer se essas duas variáveis advém do cálculo das variáveis que recebi? Não entendi bem o que elas representam...

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

`biXPelsPerMeter` é a resolução horizontal em pixels por metro sugerida para o dispositivo que vai exibir o bitmap. O aplicativo pode usar esse valor para selecionar dentro de um grupo de bitmaps qual a imagem que melhor se adéqua as características do dispositivo de exibição.

`biYPelsPerMeter`é a resolução vertical em pixels por metro sugerida para o dispositivo que vai exibir o bitmap. O aplicativo pode usar esse valor para selecionar dentro de um grupo de bitmaps qual a imagem que melhor se adéqua as características do dispositivo de exibição.

Esses valores eram utilizados normalmente em fontes bitmap. As primeiras fontes bitmap eram fixas em 96 DPI então colocaram essas propriedades para que pudessem ser selecionados os glifos que melhor se adequassem ao dispositivo em que seria rasterizado.

Para imagens esses valores não possuem significância. Mas se quiser saber como calcular os valores:

```
biXPelsPerMeter = Round(width / comprimento do dispositivo em metros)
biYPelsPerMeter = Round(height / altura do dispositivo em metros)
```